# Setting CSS style with dart

Tags: css, dart

Is there an equivalent for the jQuery `$.css` function in dart?

I can *read* the (computed) style of an element, but as far as I can see there is no way of setting a style.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [Element.style](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-dom-html.Element#id_style) isnt enough ?

```
myDiv.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
myDiv.style.setProperty('-webkit-cssexperimental','value');
```

It's also working with a multi elements selector:

```
querySelectorAll('div').style.backgroundColor = 'green'; //color every div
```

Comment: for whatever reason I tried that before and it didn't work.anyway, thanks, that's what I needed.